# Parse CFResponse to Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a CFResponse, which I would like to parse into an array like this:

```
$response = $this->scan($query);        
$array = $response->body->Items->to_array();
print_r($array);
```

This gives me an empty CFArray, for some reason, while

```
$response->body->Items->to_json();
```

other hand gives me this:

```
{"userID":{"S":"someemail@me.com"},"password":{"S":"secretPassword"}}
```

which is only the first row.
However, this is what I get through $response->body;

```
CFSimpleXML Object ( [ConsumedCapacityUnits] => 0.5 [Count] => 2 [Items] => Array ( [0] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [userID] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [S] => someemail@me.com ) [password] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [S] => secretPassword ) ) [1] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [userID] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [S] => somemoreemail@me.com ) [password] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [S] => secretPassword ) ) ) [ScannedCount] => 2 )
```

As you can see here, Items is an array. It's a SimpleXMLIterator object.
There are two rows being returned.

By calling Items, I only get the first object. How can I parse all children into an array, or at least make a json string? I've tried [getChildren()](http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php), which didn't work.
Also, why isn't `to_array()` working?

Comment: If `Items` is an array, have you tried just `$array = $response->body->Items;`?

Comment: Yes, like I said, it only returns the first object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query_response = $db->query(array(
        'TableName'    => $tableName,
        'HashKeyValue' => $db->attribute($peer)
));

if (!$query_response->isOK()){
    die(json_encode(CFUtilities::convert_response_to_array($query_response)));
}

$ps = array();

foreach ($query_response->body->Items as $item)
{
    if (empty($item)) continue;
    $p = array();
    $p['P'] = (string) $item->p->S;
    $p['TIME'] = (integer) $item->TIME->N;
    $p['STATUS'] = (string) $item->STATUS->S;
    $p['ICON'] = (string) $v->ICON->S;
    array_push($ps,$p);
}
echo json_encode($ps);
```

Comment: I did it with another foreach-loop, but the string-cast did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem optimal. If you look at the source code, here's what it does: return json_decode(json_encode($response), true);